# Why does this python code is not translating the words?

Tags: python

why is this python code not working? I can't figure out the problem.
he always print the same word...

```
woerterbuch = {"He" :" Er", "She" : "Sie", "it":"es", "Hello":"Hallo", "How":"Wie", "Are":"Geht", "You":"Dir"}

wort = input("Geben Sie den zu übersetzenden Satz ein: ")
woerter = wort.split()


uebersetzung_wort = ""

for wort in woerter:
    wort = wort.lower()

    if wort in woerterbuch:
        uebersetzung = woerterbuch[wort]
    else:
        uebersetzung = wort

    uebersetzung_wort = uebersetzung_wort + " " + uebersetzung

print("Die Übersetzung dieses Satzes ist: ", uebersetzung_wort)
```

Comment: The keys in your `dict` are all (well, mostly) title-cased; if you input `He`, you are checking if `"He".lower() == "he"` is in the `dict`, which is false.

Comment: Agree with @chepner; this works perfectly for `'it':'es'` because the key is lowercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have capital letters in woerterbuch but you look for only lower case because of wort = wort.lower(). Try changing  woerterbuch to :

```
woerterbuch = {"he" :" Er", "she" : "Sie", "it":"es", "hello":"Hallo", "how":"Wie", "are":"Geht", "you":"Dir"}
```

and then it will work correctly.

Comment: Perfect! is works thank you! Is it also possible to code this case: if I write "er" that it will translate the text also in the other way? So the anwser should be "he" ?

Comment: It might be easier to use a second dictionary for that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you lowercase your word here: `wort = wort.lower()` but the key in your dict are not lowercased.

You can do the following:

```
woerterbuch = {"He" :" Er", "She" : "Sie", "it":"es", "Hello":"Hallo", "How":"Wie", "Are":"Geht", "You":"Dir"}
woerterbuch_lowered = {key.lower():value for key,value in woerterbuch.items()}
for wort in woerter:
    wort = wort.lower()
    uebersetzung = woerterbuch_lowered.get(wort,wort)
    uebersetzung_wort = uebersetzung_wort + " " + uebersetzung
```

Answer (score 0):

You convert your words (woerter? ;->) to lowercase with:

```
wort = wort.lower()
```

but some keys in your dictionary start with uppercase. Remove the above line and your code should work (despite being unglaublich hässlich)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple reasons that you'll run into issue translating from a technical perspective. From a linguistic perspective is another question. As Gabip already pointed out, the keys in your dictionary are not lowercased.

In addition to that, you should sanitize your input of punctuation. When I input "Hallo, wie geht es?", neither "Hallo" nor "es" will be translated because your dictionary never gets those as keys. It gets "Hallo," and "es?" which are not keys in your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

import cv2
import pathlib

mycascade = pathlib.Path(cv2.**file**).parent.absolute() / "data/haarcascade_frontalface_def"

clf = cv2.CascadeClassifier(str(mycascade))

cam = cv2.videoCapture(0)

with True:
_ , frame = cam.read()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

```
  faces = clf.detectMultiScele(
      gray,
      scaleFactor = 1.1,
      minNeighbors = 3,
      minsize = (30,30),
      flogs = cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
  )

  for (x,y,width,height) in faces:
      cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), [x + width, y + height], [(0,0,255)],4)
```

cv2.imshow('MrRobot', frame)
if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
break

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).